# VMs are not getting static IP from Vagrantfile

Tags: networking, vagrant, macos-sierra

I'm beginner in networking stuff and also I'm just starting with VMs.
I'm doing examples from "Ansible for Devops" and in chapter 3, I'm supposed to create three VMs and set a private network with static ip.

My Vagrant file looks like that:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "geerlingguy/centos7"
  config.ssh.insert_key = false
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
    v.memory = 256
    v.linked_clone = true
  end

  config.vm.define "app1" do |app|
    app.vm.hostname = "orc-app1.dev"
    app.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.4"
  end

  config.vm.define "app2" do |app|
    app.vm.hostname = "orc-app2.dev"
    app.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.5"
  end

  config.vm.define "db" do |db|
    db.vm.hostname = "orc-db.dev"
    db.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.6"
  end
end
```

Vagrant loges:

```
❯ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'app1' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'app2' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'db' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> app1: Cloning VM...
==> app1: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> app1: Checking if box 'geerlingguy/centos7' is up to date...
==> app1: Setting the name of the VM: 3_app1_1485309004899_30536
==> app1: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2202.
==> app1: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> app1: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    app1: Adapter 1: nat
    app1: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> app1: Forwarding ports...
    app1: 22 (guest) => 2202 (host) (adapter 1)
==> app1: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> app1: Booting VM...
==> app1: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    app1: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2202
    app1: SSH username: vagrant
    app1: SSH auth method: private key
    app1: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
==> app1: Machine booted and ready!
==> app1: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> app1: Setting hostname...
==> app1: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> app2: Cloning VM...
==> app2: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> app2: Checking if box 'geerlingguy/centos7' is up to date...
==> app2: Setting the name of the VM: 3_app2_1485309032690_32260
==> app2: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2203.
==> app2: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> app2: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    app2: Adapter 1: nat
    app2: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> app2: Forwarding ports...
    app2: 22 (guest) => 2203 (host) (adapter 1)
==> app2: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> app2: Booting VM...
==> app2: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    app2: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2203
    app2: SSH username: vagrant
    app2: SSH auth method: private key
    app2: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
==> app2: Machine booted and ready!
==> app2: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> app2: Setting hostname...
==> app2: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> db: Cloning VM...
==> db: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> db: Checking if box 'geerlingguy/centos7' is up to date...
==> db: Setting the name of the VM: 3_db_1485309060266_65663
==> db: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2204.
==> db: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> db: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    db: Adapter 1: nat
    db: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> db: Forwarding ports...
    db: 22 (guest) => 2204 (host) (adapter 1)
==> db: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> db: Booting VM...
==> db: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    db: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2204
    db: SSH username: vagrant
    db: SSH auth method: private key
    db: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
==> db: Machine booted and ready!
==> db: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> db: Setting hostname...
==> db: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
```

And Vagrant SSH-config:

```
Host app1
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2202
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /Users/mst/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL

Host app2
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2203
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /Users/mst/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL

Host db
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2204
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /Users/mst/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

So as You can see the machines didn't get those static ips I set for them and I can't connect to them using it. They just got a localhost IP and some high ports. In that example, I should work on that machines using ansible and use that static ips in the inventory file, so they should have it set correctly.

Any ideas?

macOS Sierra
Vagrant 1.9.1
VirtualBox 5.1.14

Thanks

EDIT: The machines are using CentOS and ip addr output is:

```
[root@orc-app1 vagrant]# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:dd:23:fa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3
       valid_lft 86067sec preferred_lft 86067sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fedd:23fa/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:4d:38:fc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with vagrant 1.9.0 . My co worker had an issue with it that nfs shares would not mount corectly if 1.9.1 and it related to the fact that the box didn't add one necessary interface automatically.

Downgrading to 1.9.0 fixed this.

There are couple of open issues on the vagrants github and they relate to rhel/centos 7 specifically.

This is one of them https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/8138

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed based on the example - the file for the network interface has been correctly created by vagrant

```
[vagrant@orc-app2 ~]$ cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts
[vagrant@orc-app2 network-scripts]$ ll
total 236
-rw-r--r--. 1 root    root      353 25 janv. 16:06 ifcfg-enp0s3
-rw-------. 1 vagrant vagrant   214 25 janv. 16:06 ifcfg-enp0s8
```

and the content for this new network interface is correct

```
[vagrant@orc-app2 network-scripts]$ more ifcfg-enp0s8
#VAGRANT-BEGIN
# The contents below are automatically generated by Vagrant. Do not modify.
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.60.5
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
DEVICE=enp0s8
PEERDNS=no
#VAGRANT-END
```

so I just restarted the network services to try

```
[vagrant@orc-app2 network-scripts]$ sudo systemctl restart network
```

and it was ok

```
[vagrant@orc-app2 network-scripts]$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:dd:23:fa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3
       valid_lft 86391sec preferred_lft 86391sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fedd:23fa/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:42:83:e9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.60.5/24 brd 192.168.60.255 scope global enp0s8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe42:83e9/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I dont have another centos7 box to test (still working nicely with 6) to confirm its an issue with this box or with the new centos

Comment: I made edit to the post and added ip addr output. Still no interface with the ip I want.

Comment: ok tried with your config `sudo systemctl restart network` makes the trick -

Comment: Thank You. That works. But still no idea why those interfaces are not going up automatically.

Comment: yes not sure, vagrant creates the right file so probably something wrong in vagrant, might worth to create an issue against the project